# How to append some MP3s in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, mp3

How to append some MP3s in Qt by C++?

Assume I have 1.mp3 and 2.mp3, now I want to join them by Qt.

3.mp3 = 1.mp3 + 2.mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can not do this simply in Qt. But I suggest you use [mp3wrap](http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/), a nifty little command line tool to concatenate your mp3s.

So, you create a UI, where you select the files, and then pass the parameters to this command line application and let it do its magic.

You can execute commands using:

```
system("command1;command2");
```

This call will block until the commands are finished. In your case the command will be calling mp3wrap with the appropriate parameters

Good luck!

Comment: I tested it, It works correctly :D. now, I am happy so much :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Qt is a user interface library, not a swiss army knife. It doesn't process MP3s; nor does it make you breakfast. You will need to use an appropriate library or tool for this task.